# A Context-Sensitive Grammar which cannot be recognised by a Parsing Expression Grammar

Tags: grammars, context-free, parsing

It is (currently) an open question of whether every context-free grammar can be recognised by some parsing expression grammar. [[1]](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=964001.964011)

However, has it been proven that there exists an example of a context-sensitive grammar which has been proved to be unrecognised by every parsing expression grammar? Or is it theoretically possible that every context-sensitive grammar can be recognised by a parsing expression grammar too?

For example, the canonical context-sensitive grammar which is not context-free, $\{a^nb^nc^n\}$, can be parsed by a parsing expression grammar. [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Examples)

Comment: Does [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08272) paper help?